# Extract text from content control cell in Word

Tags: r, officer

I need to extract text from Word documents that contain parts formatted as Rich Text Content Control (RTCC). I am using officer. The problem is that I am not able to extract text formatted as RTCC. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
library(officer)

trtDoc <- read_docx("theFile.docx") %>%
          docx_summary()
```

The code above gives me a `data.frame` with the text, but the RTCC formatted text does not show.

Comment: This is not implemented within officer. You can unzip and extract raw xml (in `word/document.xml` with package xml2).

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to convert the document from docx into xml first?

Comment: yes, use `officer::unpack_folder`, you will get the directory you are looking for.